# Python vectorization

Tags: python, function, numpy, vectorization

I have written a function to find correlation between values such that if x is a list with values 1,2,3,4 then I have to find correlation between all possible combination; a Cartesian product.

```
import numpy as np
def myfunc(x,y):    
   if x==y:    
       return 0.0
   else:    
       return (max(np.exp(-.03*(abs(x-y)/min(x,y))),0.4))

func= np.vectorize(myfunc)
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[1]
func(x,y)
```

result is

```
array([ 0.        ,  0.97044553,  0.94176453,  0.91393119])
```

I can create a loop on values of Y from 1 to 4 and get 4 array outputs which will give me the result I need. However, I want to avoid a loop and pass both X = [1,2,3,4] and Y= [1,2,3,4] in my function which gives me

```
x=[1,2,3,4]
y=[1,2,3,4] 
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

I understand that there is a 1 to 1 comparison between both x and y list values and as per my function the result is 0. My first question is when I pass only 1 y value y=[1] , it computes the correlation with all 4 values of x but does not do the same when i pass more than one value of y. Am I missing something here ?

I recreated my function using a generator to do cross product within the function of my two list input but it gives me an error which I am not able to decode. Please review my code.

```
 def myfunc(x,y):  
   gen= ((a, b) for a in x for b in y)
   for u, v in gen:
      if u==v:    
          return 0.0
      else:    
          return (max(np.exp(-.03*(abs(u-v)/min(u,v))),0.4))  
 func= np.vectorize(myfunc)
 x=[1,2,3,4]
 y=[1,2,3,4]
 func(x,y)

File "<ipython-input-17-1dd059c216f1>", line 2, in myfunc
gen= ((a, b) for a in x for b in y)

TypeError: 'numpy.int32' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

For `x` and `y` as arrays, here's a vectorized solution using [`NumPy ufuncs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) -

```
np.where(x==y,0,(np.maximum(np.exp(-.03*(np.abs(x-y)/np.minimum(x,y))),0.4)))
```

Sample run -

```
>>> x=np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> y=np.array([1])
>>> np.where(x==y,0,(np.maximum(np.exp(-.03*(np.abs(x-y)/np.minimum(x,y))),0.4)))
array([ 0.        ,  0.97044553,  0.94176453,  0.91393119])
```

Answer (score -1):

To perform a cartesian product, I think you should create a matrix (rather than trying to vectorize a function)

```
import numpy as np
def myfunc(list_x,list_y):
    res=np.zeros([len(list_x),len(list_y)])
    for i,x in enumerate(list_x):
        for j,y in enumerate(list_y):
            if x!=y:
                res[i,j]=max(np.exp(-.03*(abs(x-y)/min(x,y))),0.4)
    return res

print(myfunc([1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]))
```

It gives:

```
[[ 0.          0.97044553  0.94176453  0.91393119]
 [ 0.97044553  0.          0.98511194  0.97044553]
 [ 0.94176453  0.98511194  0.          0.99004983]
 [ 0.91393119  0.97044553  0.99004983  0.        ]]
```

I hope I understand your problem correctly

EDIT:
anyway, vectorize performs a "for" loop silently

You can slightly increase the speed with comprehension lists:

```
def myfunc(list_x,list_y):
    def f(x,y):
        if x==y:
            return 0
        else:
            return max(np.exp(-.03*(abs(x-y)/min(x,y))),0.4)
    return [ [f(x,y) for y in list_y] for x in list_x]
```

EDIT2: OK then use Divakar's solution but you definitely need to build a matrix:

```
x=np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
y=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
np.where(x==y,0,(np.maximum(np.exp(-.03*(np.abs(x-y)/np.minimum(x,y))),0.4)))
array([[ 0.        ,  0.97044553,  0.94176453,  0.91393119],
       [ 0.97044553,  0.        ,  0.98511194,  0.97044553],
       [ 0.94176453,  0.98511194,  0.        ,  0.99004983],
       [ 0.91393119,  0.97044553,  0.99004983,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Will for loops will not slow down the processing if the list has large # of items? I was trying to vectorize to make the code faster.

Comment: @AbhinavBajpai they absolutely will. This is a very, very bad solution especially since you already have things vectorized.

Comment: vectorize does not just create a for loop silently. Numpy drops everything down to C, and thus gives you very dramatic performance improvements. Typically in the range of 20-40x. Lots of misinformation in this answer.

Comment: In the above solution x and y are different, having different number of elements as len(x)=1 and len(y)=4. For my original problem I will need one more step to convert x in the format of y. If I input x=np.array([[1,2,3,4]])
y=np.array([[1],[2],[3],[4]]) , my original function works smoothly.